# using node.js http with a godaddy site

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, socket.io

I have been looking around for this question and all of the answers seem to deal with localhost not an actual hosted website. I am trying to recreate socket.io's example chat application on my website. My website is hosted on godaddy and it's public IP address is 107.180.63.56 and since it is an https site I assume the port it is listening on is 443. this is my code to try to recreate the app:

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/webmessenger.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
  });

http.listen(443,'107.180.63.56', function(){
  console.log('listening on *:443');
});
```

the app then throws the error:

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 107.180.63.56:443

which I assume means this IP address or port is not valid. any help on whatI am doing wrong would be appreciated I have tried changing the port and I have obtained the public Ip by pinging my site and just looking on go-daddy. there is also a script in my index.html file which runs the messenger but that should not effect this aspect of the application.

thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you omit the ip: `http.listen(443, function() { })`

Comment: @JonasWilms  "Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:443"

Comment: If your hosting service already provides a web server listening on port 443 you'll certainly won't be able to run your own server on that same port.

Comment: hmm @ÁlvaroGonzález so is there any way I could recreate this app or would I have to host it myself?

Comment: is it shared hosting or vps?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GoDaddy. My hosting provider includes Node.js explicitly among the supported features and provides a control panel to enable apps.